# How to expose audio from Docker container to a Mac?

Tags: macos, audio, docker, containers, pulseaudio

I know it's possible by using pulse audio on a Linux host system But `paprefs` is built for linux not mac.

Answer (score 20):

Install [PulseAudio](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/?) on the Mac:

```
brew install pulseaudio
```

Run the daemon:

```
pulseaudio --load=module-native-protocol-tcp --exit-idle-time=-1 --daemon
```

In your Docker container:

1. Install PulseAudio, e.g., `apt-get install pulseaudio`.
2. set the following environment variable: `ENV PULSE_SERVER=docker.for.mac.localhost`

When you run it, share your `~/.config/pulse` directory with the container for authentication.

You can run a test to see if it's working like this:

```
docker run -it -e PULSE_SERVER=docker.for.mac.localhost -v ~/.config/pulse:/home/pulseaudio/.config/pulse --entrypoint speaker-test --rm jess/pulseaudio -c 2 -l 1 -t wav
```

Comment: Turns out I had stereo -> mono set in OS X accesibility settings. Stereo works fine. Thanks!

Comment: In a recent release of Docker for Mac (and Windows) they changed the magic hostname to `host.docker.internal` and I'd recommend changing the `-v` old syntax to the newer `--mount type=bind,source=~/.config/pulse,target=/home/pulseaudio/.config/pulse` to avoid creating a config on your host owned as `root` if you hadn't yet run the `brew install pulseaudio` and configured it and give you a nice error about it not existing instead of doing a bad thing, but otherwise this looks awesome.

Comment: Thanks for this. It took me a while to figure out the reason why the test was working but my own container wasn't: the mount ("-v ~/.config/pulse:/home/pulseaudio/.config/pulse") is pointed at the home directory for the "pulseaudio" user, which the jess/pulseaudio image creates. I had to change the mount to point to the home directory of my user.

Comment: @dragon788 trying to use your suggestion for mounting throws error (says it needs absolute paths). I managed to have it working by weirdly the speaker-test does not produce any output

Answer (score 18):

The Docker-for-Mac VM doesn't have any sound passthrough device, so there isn't anything that you could take advantage of from that angle. By contrast, a virtualbox or vmware fusion VM does have the ability to do passthrough audio.

I was able to get pulseaudio installed and working on OSX with the following command:

```
brew install pulseaudio
```

I was able to verify this worked by running the following, hearing sound come out of my speakers:

```
paplay cockatiel.wav
```

My next step is to find an image that has a copy of `paplay`. I found [jess/pulseaudio](https://hub.docker.com/r/jess/pulseaudio/), which appears to be intended to be a pulseaudio *server*, but I should be able to use it as a *client* as well.

I found the following guide on the Archlinux Wiki discussing setting up pulseaudio network sound: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#PulseAudio_over_network

I was able to adapt it to this situation by doing the following. I edited `/usr/local/Cellar/pulseaudio/9.0/etc/pulse/default.pa` on my mac, and uncommented the following two lines:

```
load-module module-esound-protocol-tcp
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
```

I reran `paplay cockatiel.wav` on my mac to make sure my changes still worked. the pulseaudio daemon seems to start on demand, and passes its complaints back to `paplay` to be printed on my screen if I made a typo. I still have sound with those changes to default.pa, so I'm satisfied that my changes didn't break anything.

Next, I ran the pulseaudio client in a container like this:

```
docker run --rm -v $HOME:$HOME -w $HOME -it \
  -e PULSE_SERVER=192.168.10.23 \
  -e HOME=$HOME --entrypoint paplay \
  jess/pulseaudio $HOME/cockatiel.wav
```

What this does is run a container with my local home directory as a volume. This serves two purposes. The first is the fact that my cockatiel.wav is located inside `$HOME`. The second is because both the client and the server need to have a copy of the same `~/.config/pulse/cookie` file (per that archlinux wiki guide).

The `PULSE_SERVER` environment variable is the en0 IP address of my OSX host, so paplay knows what to connect to.

The `HOME` environment variable is necessary so paplay can find the same `~/.config/pulse/cookie` file.

I was able to play sound from a container running on my docker-for-mac via pulseaudio.

As long as you get the `~/.config/pulse/cookie` file to appear in the correct location, you should be able to play sound. You don't have to use a host volume to accomplish this-- you could also do a 'docker cp', or even `COPY` it into an image.

Comment: I get the following error when running paplay piano2.wav $ paplay piano2.wav
W: [] caps.c: Normally all extra capabilities would be dropped now, but that's impossible because PulseAudio was built without capabilities support.
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

Comment: @valentin_nasta did you manage to fix the issue with installing PulseAudio on Mac?

Comment: With current PulseAudio 10.0, running "pulseaudio --daemonize=false -v" doesn't seem to start, get "W: [] socket-util.c: IP_TOS failed: Invalid argument" after adding the two module-esound-protocol-tcp / 
module-native-protocol-tcp lines.

Comment: Instead of PULSE_SERVER=192.168.10.23 I think you could use PULSE_SERVER=host.docker.internal instead?