# run pygame with audio in docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, audio, pygame

I am trying to run a pygame in a docker container but I have issues with the audio.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# This explains how to enable the video: https://skandhurkat.com/post/x-forwarding-on-docker/

FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER fnndsc "dev@babymri.org"

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
  && cd /usr/local/bin \
  && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip


RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -qqy x11-apps

RUN pip3 install pygame

WORKDIR /app

ADD paper_rock_scissor_game /app
RUN python3 setup.py install

ENV NAME World


CMD ["python3", "rock_paper_scissor/run_game.py", "-w", "-d"]
```

and I run it as:
`lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~/temporary/pygame_docker$ docker run -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix  -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY --device /dev/snd --name dsgame rockpaperscissor`

unfortunately the game crashes due to audio issues:

```
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~/temporary/pygame_docker$ docker run -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix  -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY --device /dev/snd  rockpaperscissor
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rock_paper_scissor/run_game.py", line 61, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.error: No available audio device
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~/temporary/pygame_docker$
```

Do you know how can I fix it?   The host machine is ubuntu.

A couple of references:

[How to play sound in a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083436/how-to-play-sound-in-a-docker-container)

https://skandhurkat.com/post/x-forwarding-on-docker/

UPDATE:

adding `RUN apt-get install -y libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev`                                                                                                                in the Dockerfile seems to partially fix the issue.

The laptop now outputs the sound correctly.  Still I can not find anyway to use headphones as output device.