# Docker-Java: stream real time audio

Tags: java, docker, audio

Im coding a music-streaming-server. So i created 2 docker containers,Client and Server. Now im trying to stream *.wav file* from server to client.

The following piece of code is where im trying to play the received audio data from server using AudioInputStream

```
int length = fromServer.readInt();//takes audio file length from socket
if (length > 0) {
  byte[] message = new byte[length];
  fromServer.readFully(message, 0, message.length);//reads the data in socket into array "message"

  AudioInputStream oAIS = new AudioInputStream(
  new ByteArrayInputStream(message),
  new AudioFormat(44100.0f, 16, 2, true, false),length); 
  //creates an AudioInputStream which can be used for playing the data
  AudioPlayer.main(oAIS);
 }
```

First i tested my code on *NetBeans IDE* and works great. My problem is when im runing it on docker i get `javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException`. Documentation says that is an exception indicating that a line cannot be opened because it is unavailable. This situation arises most commonly when a requested line is already in use by another application.

Im confused because i have not opened this file on another application. What might be wrong?

Comment: Is AudioPlayer a class you created or is it sun.audio.AudioPlayer?

Comment: @PhilFreihofner i lost my account so im writing from here. I created the  AudioPlayer class which includes the ```javax.sound.sampled.Clip```. and the exception accurs when im opening the clip with ```clip.open()```. Is it because docker maybe needs its own sound system?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I wanted to rule out possibility that a deprecated class was being used. IDK if the Docker you are using has sound implemented. It might be possible to check by inspecting `AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()` and `AudioSystem.getSourceLineInfo()`. Is the Docker being used a public one from docker hub that we can inspect?

Comment: This link is a little old, but the fact that it has a high upvote is a sign that the info has been relevant for many people. Maybe it will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083436/how-to-play-sound-in-a-docker-container