# Failed to open module module-native-protocol-tcp.so

Tags: pulseaudio

I am trying to share a sound card on my mac with docker so that I can play and record audio through the dockerfile.

I have read at different places like [this](https://kb.shawnchen.info/knowledge-base/docker/audio-in-docker-container/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136606/how-to-expose-audio-from-docker-container-to-a-mac) to use pulse-audio and letting it run using `pulseaudio --load=module-native-protocol-tcp --exit-idle-time=-1` however, I keep getting

```
Failed to open module module-native-protocol-tcp.so: dlopen(module-native-protocol-tcp.so, 0x0002): tried: 'module-native-protocol-tcp.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSmodule-native-protocol-tcp.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/pulseaudio/17.0/lib/pulseaudio/module-native-protocol-tcp.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/Cellar/pulseaudio/17.0/lib/pulseaudio/module-native-protocol-tcp.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/pulseaudio/17.0/lib/pulseaudio/module-native-protocol-tcp.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/Cellar/pulseaudio/17.0/lib/pulseaudio/module-native-protocol-tcp.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/module-native-protocol-tcp.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'module-native-protocol-tcp.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/module-native-protocol-tcp.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/module-native-protocol-tcp.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

in fact, I don't see `module-native-protocol-tcp.so` anywhere on my machine. I am using pulseaudio version 17.0 and installed it through the latest version of `brew`.

when I tried `pulseaudio --version` I also get

```
W: [] caps.c: Normally all extra capabilities would be dropped now, but that's impossible because PulseAudio was built without capabilities support.
pulseaudio 17.0
```